# Make gradle execute a finalizedBy task for each time it is set (multiple times)

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, gradle-task

I ran into the problem using the following situation:

To run different native testplugins in a row I dynamically create some tasks to prepare the environment appropriately for each plugin and then create a `plugin_task`  for each testplugin that hosts the dependencies.

To start the tests on the device, the plugin_task is `finalizedBy connectedAndroidTest`.

So e.g. the call `gradle plugin_name_1` works fine, it prepares the environment and starts the tests.

```
tasks.register("allTests"){}

name_list.each { test_name ->
   def prepare_dir = tasks.register("${test_name}_Prepare_Dir") {...} 
   def copy_files = tasks.register("${test_name}_Copy_Files") {...}

   def plugin_task = tasks.register(test_name){
     dependsOn prepare_dir
     dependsOn copy_files

     finalizedBy connectedAndroidTest
   }

   allTests.configure {
     dependsOn pluginTask
   }
}
```

The problem now occurs, when I try run the **allTests** task:

gradle then correctly operates over all the dynamicly created tasks "prepare_dir", "copy_files" for each of the plugins, all of them are executed.

But the **connectedAndroidTest** will only be executed at the very end of **allTests**, so only runs once. But I need this task to be executed at every end of each **plugin_task**.

The behavior of gradle is correct, as it sees that all plugin_tasks shall be finalized by connectedAndroidTest and so puts it at the end of the graph.

Is there any possibility to make gradle execute this task multiple times?
Would be glad for help.

Wrapping the **connectedAndroidTest** task into dynamically created tasks and let the plugin_tasks depend on them, does not help. Also the parameter "rerun-tasks" has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Gradle works. Each task will execute either 1 or 0 times per Gradle invocation. If you want to execute the same task multiple times (with different task inputs) then you'll need multiple task instances, not one.